# maximum length of a scaled vector in a triangle (simplex)

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a triangle (or, in general, a simplex) $T$ and a vector $\vec{s}$, I'd like to compute the quantity
$$
\max\{|x-y|: x,y\in T, x-y = \alpha \vec{s}, \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
i.e., the maximum length of a scaled vector that fits into the triangle.

I was about to start fiddling with the angles, but I thought there might be a smarter way to get the job done.

Comment: relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection#Mathematics<br> Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection

Comment: I'm quite sure you can restrict yourself to having $x$ be one of the corner and $y$ be on one of the sides of the thing, which you can do by solving for the correct $\alpha$. And then you could take the max of those values.

Comment: @xavierm02 Yes, but I'd have to check if the intersection of $x+t\vec{s}$ and the opposite edge is indeed inside the triangle. Sounds a bit `if-then-else`y to me.

Comment: @Nico: I can't really visualize simplexes, but I don't think it could be outside the triangle and be the minimum value at the same time.

Comment: @xavierm02 You're right, but that doesn't change the fact that I'd have to check if the intersection point is on the line or not.

Comment: @Nico: I don't get it. Isn't the edge/line part of the triangle?

Comment: @xavierm02 Besides, I am looking for the _maximum_.